# Using promise.all on an array of axios requests is returning all of the responses in the last object instead of spreading them out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Each object should have around 250 arrays in it, but for some reason, each of the objects has a single array except for the last one, which has 1250.

How can I spread out the responses so I can access each one individually?

```
   const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        createLocalStorage();
        let existingLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await Promise.all(
                existingLocalStorage.map(obj =>
                    coinGecko.get(`/coins/${obj[0].coin}/market_chart/`, {
                        params: {
                            vs_currency: 'usd',
                            days: obj[0].time
                        }
                    }),
                )
            );

            setCoinData(data);
            setLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

Here's the response:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWgeS.png)

I'm using create-react-app, and testing with `console.log` in the browser

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: oh sorry about that. I'm using create react app, and looking at the results with `console.log`

Comment: Damn, yea, i'm using a browser. I just redid my post with some additional info. Is there anything else I should include you think?

Comment: why are you declaring `fetchData` to be `async`, and then not `await`ing it?   You also have code missing within the `Promise.all` chunk.\

Comment: `const data = await Promise.all(existingLocalStorage.map(obj => ));` Does this not work? Also woops, I deleted some lines to test something. Missing code should be there now

Comment: could you please also share the link for codesanbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the times as strings ('day', 'week', 'month', 'year', 'max') I totally forgot I needed to convert them to number values. Since max was the only acceptable parameter, that's the only one that returned the response I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

Try calling your method like below-

```
import axios from 'axios';


 useEffect(() => {
  createLocalStorage();
  let existingLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('charts'));

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.all([api1, api2]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
    const resp1 = responses[0]
    const resp2 = responses[1]
     // use the results 
    })).catch(errors => {
     // errors.
    })
  }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```